# HTMLParseError: unknown status keyword u'cadta' in marked section, at line 1, column 54

Tags: python, html-parsing

I am getting the following error message

```
HTMLParseError: unknown status keyword u'cadta' in marked section, at line 1, column 54
```

when I try to remove HTML tags with the following code:

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []

    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)

    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)


def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html )
    return s.get_data()
```

for this piece of text by calling `strip_tags()`:

```
how to Fetch data from an XML file with tags <title> <![CADTA[text here]]> </title>?
```

What's going on here and how can I fix this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a Try / Except to catch the error and just not remove the tags for offending strings:

```
def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()

    try:
        s.feed(html.decode("utf-8"))
        return s.get_data()
    except:
        return html
```

Answer (score 2):

it should be `CDATA`, not `CADTA`. Check your syntax.

Comment: This is not my HTML.  I am trying to pre-process text to stip HTML tags for later text classification.

Comment: If you can't feed it HTML that's known to be valid, then you'll need to use tools that can actually handle invalid HTML. Look up BeautifulSoup for example.